# vim: How can you pipe the output of something that prints to the message log to a buffer?

Tags: vim, neovim

e.g. When you type `:version` it shows up in the message log. I'd like to pipe the Compilation line to `tr ' ' '\n'` to be able to read the log faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **[redir](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html)** command

```
:redir @"> | silent version | redir END | new | put
```

That will put *version* output to a new buffer

> :redi[r] @">
>
> Redirect messages to the unnamed register. For
>                           backward compatibility, the ">" after the register
>                           name can be omitted.

Comment: Does nothing for m :o Just opens a new blank window.

Comment: Which *vim* version are you using? Which OS?

Comment: Ah this doesn't work on neovim. Works on vim when I tried it again. Thanks!

Comment: Just read through the docs. It has to do with the fact that my `clipboard` variable is set and thus `:put` behaves differently without an arg.